# How does one undo editing final values in xCode AutoLayout so that Base Values once again take precedence?

Tags: ios, xcode, layout, autolayout

**TLDR: How to reset a size class so `Any  Any` once again takes precedence.**

Auto Layout can be a bit tricky. I'm starting to get a better handle on it but now I've hit a snag.

From the `Any  Any` configuration I have my constraints set pretty much how I want them.  Opening up the simulator with the iPhone 5 shows good results.

I played around with the final values for `Compact Width  Regular Height` to see what I could do.  This is for Final Values of iPhones in portrait and hence takes precedence over the Base Values of `Any  Any`.

Okay Now I didn't like the changes I tried and made a few mistakes.  **No big deal, I just want to use the values of `Any  Any` again.  *How?***  I tried clearing all constraints from `Compact Width  Regular Height` but that builds the iPhone version of the app with the lack of constraints, not the Base Values which are still set in `Any Any`. Running the sim for an iPad uses the Base Values just fine.

How do I restablish Base Values after having edited Final Values?  I see no option to re-inherit or zero-out having edited final values for constraints in the Interface builder.

For anyone confused about what I'm referring to its this little picker:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit tedious, but I haven't found a quicker way.  If you double click on the constraint in the size inspector, you will get more advanced properties on it.  From there, you will see the different values assigned to different size classes (ex: wR hR = regular width x regular height).  You can then just click the x to remove unwanted constraints, leaving the "constant" or base value.

Additionally, below that, you might see a list of constraints that are "installed".  checking/unchecking that box will add/remove the constraint from the size class.  This allows you have have some constraints active on one size, but not another.